# How do I add education and company logo to my profile?

Tags: feature-request, support, profile-page, new-users, navigation

I am a **very** new user (< 1 hour).
As I was filling out information on this site, I believe that I saw a section in *profile* about *education* and a place to insert a 60x60 pixel company *logo* in the employment section.
I skipped over those, because I didn't have the information handy; but now I can't get back to a page where I can fill it in.
Is it possible to navigate to pages on this site where I can add supplemental information to my education and work profile?
Thanks!

Comment: You can edit your profile at https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/edit/current . But I don't know about any section on education or pixel company logos there...

Comment: Bruce, is [this an element](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/302494/3648282) of what you are asking / will want? If so your question is specific to MSO and not here MSE.

Comment: Are you thinking of your [developer story](https://stackoverflow.com/users/story/16138487)? That is a feature of only Stack Overflow.